# Using dplyr in R to create column with ranking position after each round of competition

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Can you give me a hand here?
This is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(worldfootballR)


df_premiere_20 <- get_match_results(country = 'ENG', gender = 'M', season_end_year = c(2020)) %>%
                                    select(Season_End_Year, Wk, Date, Home, HomeGoals, Away, AwayGoals)
df_premiere_20 %>% group_by(Home) %>% mutate(Team_points = case_when(HomeGoals < AwayGoals ~ 0,
                                                  HomeGoals == AwayGoals ~ 1,
                                                  HomeGoals > AwayGoals ~ 3),
                          Cumulative_points = cumsum(Team_points))
```

All I want is to create a column that gives me the position of each team after each round (`Wk` column). The criteria are:

`Cumulative points` > `AwayGoals` > Alphabetical order of `Home`

If Cumulative points are the same I will look at the `AwayGoals`column.

If the `AwayGoals`column values are the same I will organize the rank position with teams alphabetical order.

Of course the rank starts at `1` and ends at `20`.

Any help?

Comment: Since this is a `dplyr` question and the `worldfootballR` part is presumably working fine, could you please include the output of `dput(df_premiere_20)` that results after you've run the code above? I'd rather not download a package just to review the question.

Answer (score 1):

I expect the code below should work, by grouping each week, sorting, and adding a rank based on position within each group.

```
df_premiere_20 %>%
    group_by(Wk) %>% 
    arrange(-Cumulative_points, -AwayGoals, Home) %>%
    mutate(rank = row_number()) %>%
    ungroup()
```